# Importar Tabela Internet Para Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, tabela-html, importação

É possivel importar a seguinte tabela nesse site para o excel usando VBA ?

O caminho é o seguinte :

http://www.bmfbovespa.com.br/pt_br/servicos/emprestimo-de-ativos/emprestimos-registrados.htm

1-) Clicar em lista completa
2-) Clicar em (um dia útil)

Eu tentei usar a ferramenta New Web Query do excel mas aparentemente para essa pagina não funciona.

Comment: Talvez ajude. Os Empréstimos registrados - BTC, trata-se de um arquivo texto com tamanho de colunas predefinidas (ver pdf com especificações no site). Manualmente é possível (na aba de Dados) iniciar uma conexão De Texto indicando o endereço do link  `http://bvmf.bmfbovespa.com.br/BancoTitulosBTC/EmprestimoRegistrado.aspx?idioma=pt-br&download=planilha`

Comment: A tabela completa pode ser baixada manualmente iniciando conexão Da Web indicando o link `http://bvmf.bmfbovespa.com.br/BancoTitulosBTC/EmprestimoRegistrado.aspx?idioma=pt-br&periodo=15` e selecionando somente a tabela

Comment: Boa muito Obrigado